# IIS: shortcut to folder

Tags: iis

considder this:

folder in initpub:
folder1
folder2
folder3

In folder1 I place all the files of my website.
In folder2 I place a shortcut to folder1 and add a web.config file.
In folder3 I place a shortcut to folder1 and add a slightly different web.config file.

In IIS I create an application for folder2 as well as for folder3.

Would this work?
Or is there another way to do something simulair.

Basically the only difference is in the web.config.

Comment: "In IIS I create an application for both folder2 and folder3" is impossible. An IIS application can only map to a single folder. So, you have to edit the question and make things super clear. Show screen shots if it is difficult to describe.

Comment: Why do you create an application for both folders? An application can only map one physical path.

Comment: What you are trying to do is running 3 web applications with same source code but a different web.config file? If so, you should deploy the same deployment package with the web.config to the folders separately, and create 3 different IIS sites, each of the site map to a folder.